# Foursquare API get venue longitude and latitude

Tags: foursquare, latitude-longitude

Can I use the foursquare API to get the venue coordinates ( longitude and latitude ) based on the venue name (or maybe address)?

I'm new in this, so any help and tips will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally the Foursquare API excels at translating from a given lat/lon to venues that are nearby. However, if you have the Foursquare venue ID of the venue in question, you can very easily grab the lat/lon of this place from a [venue detail](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/venues) response.

If you don't have the ID and still want to go from name => lat/lon, you can always use [venues/search](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search) and pass in the venue name as the `query` param. Supplying `intent=match` will also give you better results for exact name matches.